# Black screen after login, update from win 7 to win 10

Tags: windows-10

I just updated from windows 7 to windows 10..

I am able to see login screen and after I put my password, I see my desktop for 2-3 seconds and then it just goes black with the cursor. 
I tried to type 'explorer.exe' in new task but nothing changes...

I also opened control panel via task manager, my drivers seem just fine - there is no undefined ones, it says that best one is currently in use when I try to update my graphic card (as I can hear the sound, I thought problem might be graphic card)...

My laptop is HP-Envy4-1000en, using Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000

Same thing happens if I try to enter any safe mode (with networking or without)..

Other info about my PC:

Intel(r) Core(tm)i3-2367M CPU @ 1.4Ghz
RAM: 16GB
64bit OS

Please help!

Comment: most probably hardware compatibility issue , you might need update graphic driver

Comment: @mussdroid I did, device manager says 'The best driver software for your device is already installed' when I try to update my drivers.. Any other idea? Thanks!